# Ridiculous memory size for dataset array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dataset, tensorflow2.0

```
try: 
    with open(f'F:/Storage/readyDataset{IMG_SIZE}.pkl', 'rb') as save:
        training_data = pickle.load(save)
    print("Using dataset")
except:
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)
        print("Gathering Dataset: {}%".format(class_num*50))
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img))
            new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
            training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
    print("Gathering Dataset: 100%\nSaving dataset")
    with open(f'F:/Storage/readyDataset{IMG_SIZE}.pkl', 'wb') as save:
        pickle.dump(training_data, save, protocol=4)

print("Compiling Data")
random.shuffle(training_data)
for features, label in training_data:
    X.append(features)
    Y.append(label)
X = np.array(X).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3) / 255
Y = np.array(Y)
print("Finished Compiling Data")
```

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 39.8 GiB for an array with shape (6800, 512, 512, 3) and data type float64

I am currently trying to use a custom dataset of 6800 images in TensorFlow v2. The dataset is less than 3 GB but after compiling the data it says its 40GB. How is this possible? I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: Give the array shape, that's the expected size range, `(6800* 512* 512* 3 *8)/1e9`.  How are you measuring the dataset size?

Comment: Did you perhaps forget to multiply by the size of the float? Or 3 channels?

Comment: @hpaulj Its 512px by 512px and the 3 is RGB, I'm not sure why you would add an 8? also what does /1e9 do?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Im not sure what you mean by multiplying the size of the float, the 3 should represent the RGB right?

Comment: @Poofy38. Your data is being loaded into an array with data type `np.float64` according to the error message. `float64` is a 64-bit, or 8-byte number. That's what I'm talking about, and that's where hpaulj's factor of 8 is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.data.Dataset` to create your dataset to optimize memory consumption.
For TensorFlow input pipelines with a different type of data, you can follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#consuming_python_generators) official documentation.